# Why is my syntax wrong in my JOIN statement?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a simple SQL query with a where and a join. I tried to execute this command : 
`SELECT * FROM gym_service WHERE gym_id = ? JOIN services ON service_id = id`. The ? is by the value in the code :

```
persistent.transaction(tx => {
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM gym_service WHERE gym_id = ? JOIN services ON service_id = id', [gym.id],
            (t, s) => {
                console.log(s)
            }, (t, e) => {
                console.log(e)
            })
        })
```

However, I always get this strange error : `Error code 1: near "JOIN": syntax error`

I believe everything is done properly, what is the issue with my code ?

Comment: `JOIN` is an operator in the `FROM` clause.  `WHERE` is a clause that *follows* the `FROM` clause.

Comment: You must first read how to ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, here on `SO`. The first point is: "search and research". You should be able to see a search field on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify the joins in the from clause

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    gym_service g
    INNER JOIN services s ON g.service_id = s.id
WHERE
    g.gym_id = ?
```

See: [SQL Joins (w3schools.com)](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Answer (score 0):

WHERE clause should be used after joining the tables.

For Joining tables use INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT OUTER JOIN as per your need.

Below query will fulfill your above requirement.

`SELECT * 
FROM gym_service gs
INNER JOIN services s ON gs.service_id = s.id
WHERE gs.gym_id = ?`